# How to set the dimensions to get a poster A1

Tags: beamerposter, posters

I found this template to create posters in latex, but, even by following the instructions, I'm not able to change the dimensions to get a poster A1. Could you help me please? here is the code
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster

Comment: Change the measures of the paper, these are lines 49 and 50 of the code.

Comment: The A1 paper dimensions are (width 33.1 x height 23.4) inches

Comment: I tried it, but when I compile the file again  it shows only (and not entirely) 3 columns.

Comment: Without changing anything in `beamerposter.sty` it works for me setting `\usepackage[scale=0.8,size=a1]{beamerposter}` and using `\setlength{\paperwidth}{36in}` and `\setlength{\paperheight}{24in}` in `main.tex`

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the A1 size. The A1 size is height=33.1in and width=23.4in.

Comment: @Criis That was following the directives in the forum. What about: `\usepackage[scale=0.78,size=a1]{beamerposter}`, `\setlength{\paperwidth}{33.1in}` and `\setlength{\paperheight}{23.4in}`?

Comment: Crossref: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=25755&p=87933&hilit=beamerposter+33.3#p87932

Comment: @karlkoeller Wanna write an answer?

Answer (score 8):

To get it in A1 format, replace the line

```
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
```

with

```
\usepackage[scale=0.78,size=a1]{beamerposter}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{33.1in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{23.4in}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for saving my poster.  For other people who are using the jacobs landscape poster, do not forget to adjust the `\setlength{\topmargin}{-5in}` value, as this may have a small visual impact now that the dimensions are different.