# Switching from A0 to A1 poster

Tags: posters

Here is a template: https://www.overleaf.com/2947235kjbjrt#/8039373/

What do I need to do to switch to A1 successfully?

You could try changing `a0` to `a1` in line 22 as follows:

```
\documentclass[a1,portrait]{a0poster}
```

But that doesn't work properly, as some of text overflows etc.

Thanks

Comment: Some helpful hints can be obtained from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141116/how-to-set-the-dimensions-to-get-a-poster-a1?rq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243831/changing-a0-poster-template-to-a1-format

Comment: I have looked at them and I can't see how they help. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @TuringMachine: Apparently the hints in Leucippus' comments were helpful to the O.P. of that question -- Did you try it?

Comment: @TuringMachine: If I use the document in your link above, I get a normal document with (almost the A1 dimensions) and no overflowing etc.

Comment: Depending on your needs, the very simplest way to use this style for an A1 poster would be to create an A0 poster and scale it by 0.7121.

Comment: I should have stated more clearly to try something along the lines of change the scale. The components were stated in a comment of the first link as : \usepackage[scale=0.8,size=a1] and \setlength{\paperwidth}{36in} and \setlength{\paperheight}{24in}.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `a1` class option is the right first step.  But your file contains some dimensions which are of a fixed size, rather than being relative to the page size.  In particular, additionally you need to change

- `\columnsep=100pt`
- the width of the logo in `\includegraphics[width=20cm]{logo.png}`

Reducing to `70%` of these values is a reasonable choice.  You might consider changing some of the vertical skips too, typically `\vspace` commands.

Additionally the heading line is missing a `\noindent` producing an overfull box.  The file below compiles without overfull boxes, but has a number of underfull boxes.  I have adjusted the spacing a little in the title.

[image: Sample output]

```
%\title{LaTeX Portrait Poster Template}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% a0poster Portrait Poster
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (22/06/13)
%
% The a0poster class was created by:
% Gerlinde Kettl and Matthias Weiser (tex@kettl.de)
% 
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a1]{a0poster}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol} % This is so we can have multiple columns of text side-by-side
\columnsep=70pt % This is the amount of white space between the columns in the poster
\columnseprule=3pt % This is the thickness of the black line between the columns in the poster

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Specify colors by their 'svgnames', for a full list of all colors available see here: http://www.latextemplates.com/svgnames-colors

\usepackage{times} % Use the times font
%\usepackage{palatino} % Uncomment to use the Palatino font

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for table
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} % For math fonts, symbols and environments
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows wrapping text around tables and figures

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   POSTER HEADER 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% The header is divided into two boxes:
% The first is 75% wide and houses the title, subtitle, names, university/organization and contact information
% The second is 25% wide and houses a logo for your university/organization or a photo of you
% The widths of these boxes can be easily edited to accommodate your content as you see fit

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.75\linewidth}
\veryHuge \color{NavyBlue} \textbf{Unnecessarily Complicated Research Title} \color{Black}\\[0.5cm] % Title
\Huge\textit{An Exploration of Complexity}\\[2cm] % Subtitle
\huge \textbf{John Smith \& James Smith}\\[0.5cm] % Author(s)
\huge University and Department Name\\[0.4cm] % University/organization
\Large \texttt{john@LaTeXTemplates.com} --- 1 (000) 111 1111\\
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=14cm]{logo.png}\\
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm} % A bit of extra whitespace between the header and poster content

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{multicols}{2} % This is how many columns your poster will be broken into, a portrait poster is generally split into 2 columns

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\color{Navy} % Navy color for the abstract

\begin{abstract}

Sed fringilla tempus hendrerit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam ut elit sit amet metus lobortis consequat sit amet in libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vel sem magna. Nunc at convallis urna. isus ante. Pellentesque condimentum dui. Etiam sagittis purus non tellus tempor volutpat. Donec et dui non massa tristique adipiscing. Quisque vestibulum eros eu. Phasellus imperdiet, tortor vitae congue bibendum, felis enim sagittis lorem, et volutpat ante orci sagittis mi. Morbi rutrum laoreet semper. Morbi accumsan enim nec tortor consectetur non commodo nisi sollicitudin. Proin sollicitudin. Pellentesque eget orci eros. Fusce ultricies, tellus et pellentesque fringilla, ante massa luctus libero, quis tristique purus urna nec nibh.

\end{abstract}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\color{SaddleBrown} % SaddleBrown color for the introduction

\section*{Introduction}

Aliquam non lacus dolor, \textit{a aliquam quam} \cite{Smith:2012qr}. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla in nibh mauris. Donec vel ligula nisi, a lacinia arcu. Sed mi dui, malesuada vel consectetur et, egestas porta nisi. Sed eleifend pharetra dolor, et dapibus est vulputate eu. \textbf{Integer faucibus elementum felis vitae fringilla.} In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis tristique rutrum nisl, nec vulputate elit porta ut. Donec sodales sollicitudin turpis sed convallis. Etiam mauris ligula, blandit adipiscing condimentum eu, dapibus pellentesque risus.

\textit{Aliquam auctor}, metus id ultrices porta, risus enim cursus sapien, quis iaculis sapien tortor sed odio. Mauris ante orci, euismod vitae tincidunt eu, porta ut neque. Aenean sapien est, viverra vel lacinia nec, venenatis eu nulla. Maecenas ut nunc nibh, et tempus libero. Aenean vitae risus ante. Pellentesque condimentum dui. Etiam sagittis purus non tellus tempor volutpat. Donec et dui non massa tristique adipiscing.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\color{DarkSlateGray} % DarkSlateGray color for the rest of the content

\section*{Main Objectives}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
\item Nullam at mi nisl. Vestibulum est purus, ultricies cursus volutpat sit amet, vestibulum eu.
\item Praesent tortor libero, vulputate quis elementum a, iaculis.
\item Phasellus a quam mauris, non varius mauris. Fusce tristique, enim tempor varius porta, elit purus commodo velit, pretium mattis ligula nisl nec ante.
\item Ut adipiscing accumsan sapien, sit amet pretium.
\item Estibulum est purus, ultricies cursus volutpat
\item Nullam at mi nisl. Vestibulum est purus, ultricies cursus volutpat sit amet, vestibulum eu.
\item Praesent tortor libero, vulputate quis elementum a, iaculis.
\end{enumerate}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MATERIALS AND METHODS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section*{Materials and Methods}

Fusce magna risus, molestie ut porttitor in, consectetur sed mi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque consectetur blandit pellentesque. Sed odio justo, viverra nec porttitor vel, lacinia a nunc. Suspendisse pulvinar euismod arcu, sit amet accumsan enim fermentum quis. In id mauris ut dui feugiat egestas. Vestibulum ac turpis lacinia nisl commodo sagittis eget sit amet sapien.

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection*{Mathematical Section}

Nulla vel nisl sed mauris auctor mollis non sed. 

\begin{equation}
E = mc^{2}
\label{eqn:Einstein}
\end{equation}

Curabitur mi sem, pulvinar quis aliquam rutrum. (1) edf (2)
, $\Omega=[-1,1]^3$, maecenas leo est, ornare at. $z=-1$ edf $z=1$ sed interdum felis dapibus sem. $x$ set $y$ ytruem. 
Turpis $j$ amet accumsan enim $y$-lacina; 
ref $k$-viverra nec porttitor $x$-lacina. 

Vestibulum ac diam a odio tempus congue. Vivamus id enim nisi:

\begin{eqnarray}
\cos\bar{\phi}_k Q_{j,k+1,t} + Q_{j,k+1,x}+\frac{\sin^2\bar{\phi}_k}{T\cos\bar{\phi}_k} Q_{j,k+1} &=&\nonumber\\ 
-\cos\phi_k Q_{j,k,t} + Q_{j,k,x}-\frac{\sin^2\phi_k}{T\cos\phi_k} Q_{j,k}\label{edgek}
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
\cos\bar{\phi}_j Q_{j+1,k,t} + Q_{j+1,k,y}+\frac{\sin^2\bar{\phi}_j}{T\cos\bar{\phi}_j} Q_{j+1,k}&=&\nonumber \\
-\cos\phi_j Q_{j,k,t} + Q_{j,k,y}-\frac{\sin^2\phi_j}{T\cos\phi_j} Q_{j,k}.\label{edgej}
\end{eqnarray} 

Nulla sed arcu arcu. Duis et ante gravida orci venenatis tincidunt. Fusce vitae lacinia metus. Pellentesque habitant morbi. $\mathbf{A}\underline{\xi}=\underline{\beta}$ Vim $\underline{\xi}$ enum nidi $3(P+2)^{2}$ lacina. Id feugain $\mathbf{A}$ nun quis; magno.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RESULTS 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section*{Results}

Donec faucibus purus at tortor egestas eu fermentum dolor facilisis. Maecenas tempor dui eu neque fringilla rutrum. Mauris \emph{lobortis} nisl accumsan. Aenean vitae risus ante.
%
\begin{wraptable}{l}{12cm} % Left or right alignment is specified in the first bracket, the width of the table is in the second
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{\color{Green} Table caption}
\end{wraptable}
%
Phasellus imperdiet, tortor vitae congue bibendum, felis enim sagittis lorem, et volutpat ante orci sagittis mi. Morbi rutrum laoreet semper. Morbi accumsan enim nec tortor consectetur non commodo nisi sollicitudin. Proin sollicitudin. Pellentesque eget orci eros. Fusce ultricies, tellus et pellentesque fringilla, ante massa luctus libero, quis tristique purus urna nec nibh.

Nulla ut porttitor enim. Suspendisse venenatis dui eget eros gravida tempor. Mauris feugiat elit et augue placerat ultrices. Morbi accumsan enim nec tortor consectetur non commodo. Pellentesque condimentum dui. Etiam sagittis purus non tellus tempor volutpat. Donec et dui non massa tristique adipiscing. Quisque vestibulum eros eu. Phasellus imperdiet, tortor vitae congue bibendum, felis enim sagittis lorem, et volutpat ante orci sagittis mi. Morbi rutrum laoreet semper. Morbi accumsan enim nec tortor consectetur non commodo nisi sollicitudin.

\begin{center}\vspace{1cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{placeholder}
\captionof{figure}{\color{Green} Figure caption}
\end{center}\vspace{1cm}

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam placerat, risus ac.

Adipiscing lectus in magna blandit:

\begin{center}\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2} \\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{\color{Green} Table caption}
\end{center}\vspace{1cm}

Vivamus sed nibh ac metus tristique tristique a vitae ante. Sed lobortis mi ut arcu fringilla et adipiscing ligula rutrum. Aenean turpis velit, placerat eget tincidunt nec, ornare in nisl. In placerat.

\begin{center}\vspace{1cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{placeholder}
\captionof{figure}{\color{Green} Figure caption}
\end{center}\vspace{1cm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONCLUSIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\color{SaddleBrown} % SaddleBrown color for the conclusions to make them stand out

\section*{Conclusions}

\begin{itemize}
\item Pellentesque eget orci eros. Fusce ultricies, tellus et pellentesque fringilla, ante massa luctus libero, quis tristique purus urna nec nibh. Phasellus fermentum rutrum elementum. Nam quis justo lectus.
\item Vestibulum sem ante, hendrerit a gravida ac, blandit quis magna.
\item Donec sem metus, facilisis at condimentum eget, vehicula ut massa. Morbi consequat, diam sed convallis tincidunt, arcu nunc.
\item Nunc at convallis urna. isus ante. Pellentesque condimentum dui. Etiam sagittis purus non tellus tempor volutpat. Donec et dui non massa tristique adipiscing.
\end{itemize}

\color{DarkSlateGray} % Set the color back to DarkSlateGray for the rest of the content

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FORTHCOMING RESEARCH
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section*{Forthcoming Research}

Vivamus molestie, risus tempor vehicula mattis, libero arcu volutpat purus, sed blandit sem nibh eget turpis. Maecenas rutrum dui blandit lorem vulputate gravida. Praesent venenatis mi vel lorem tempor at varius diam sagittis. Nam eu leo id turpis interdum luctus a sed augue. Nam tellus.

 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\nocite{*} % Print all references regardless of whether they were cited in the poster or not
\bibliographystyle{plain} % Plain referencing style
\bibliography{sample} % Use the example bibliography file sample.bib

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section*{Acknowledgements}

Etiam fermentum, arcu ut gravida fringilla, dolor arcu laoreet justo, ut imperdiet urna arcu a arcu. Donec nec ante a dui tempus consectetur. Cras nisi turpis, dapibus sit amet mattis sed, laoreet.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not in portrait mode anymore.

Comment: @Astrid You can just add the "portrait" option `\documentclass[a1,portrait]{a0poster}` if you wish.

Comment: No sure, but then your solutions do not work anymore, and we have overflow in the left-hand column (at least on my editor).

Comment: Apologies, that should be right-hand column.

Comment: @Astrid The only overflow I get is from the logo - reducing its width fixes that problem.